# New admin: mounting folders on an external drive inside users' home directories

Tags: users

First time admin here.

I am setting up a file server for the family using an RPi and an ext4 formatted external hard drive.

Each family member has a user account on the RPi. Let's call them A, B and C. On the external drive there is one folder for each of them, also named A, B and C. Each of these folders have the corresponding user set as owner.

I want to mount these folders so that they are accessible directly inside each user's home directory (so that, e.g. there would appear to be a folder /home/A/external, which in reality is the A folder in the external drive).

There is also a music library on the external drive, that I would like one user (A) to have full access to, but the other users to have read access to.

Right now, the external drive is mounted to /media/pi/WD10TB.

Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: See Ant0ine64's answer below about the home dir links.  For the music directory, just make user A it's owner and the owner of all files below it and set the permissions of the music directory to 755 (and any subdirs) and set the perms on the music files to 644.  If your users are all in the same group, you could use 750 and 640 instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different between **directory** and **devices** :

- A **directory** is somewhere on your filsesystem
- A storage **device** is physical(ex : hard dive) or logical(ex : partition) and it can be mounted

Looking at your setup, your drive is mounted as one device in `/media/pi/WD10TB`, it contains directories accesibles by the users.
If you want those to apear in the user home directories you may use symbolic links like so:

```
ln -s /media/pi/WD10TB/A /home/A/external
```

This will link the directory in the drive to this symoblic reference, for the user it will look like it's just a directory.

Comment: Given the OP's question, I think the link would look more like this:  ln -s /media/pi/WD10TB/A  /home/A/external

Comment: @miken you're right, i'll edit this